# ajax infinate scroll to preload content

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, infinite-scroll, preloader

I have an infinate scrolling function that loads data via ajax. I would like to load the next set of data or at least, images in advance - preload the next page of content.

I have tried adding .load instead of .ajax - but it still seems to load the data directly not from a 'cached' version.

Any ideas appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var count = 2;
        var total = <?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>;
        var ready = true; //Assign the flag here
        var processing;

        $(window).data('ajaxready', true).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).data('ajaxready') == false) return;

                if  ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){
                    $(window).data('ajaxready', false);
                    if (count > total){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        loadArticle(count);
                    }
                    count++;
                    }

        });

        function loadArticle(pageNumber){
              $('a#inifiniteLoader').show('fast');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    type:'POST',
                    data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop',
                    success: function(html){
                      $('a#inifiniteLoader').hide('1000');
                      $(".newsfeed").append(html);   // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
                      console.log('fire');
                    //stop multiple firing
                      $(window).data('ajaxready', true);
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First I should say what is infinite scroll:**

> Traditionally, the user would have to click on next page or previous page to visit older post content. However, recently there is
>   a new trend started by popular sites (such as facebook and twitter) in
>   which they automatically load the next page content once the user hits
>   the bottom of the post. This technique has proven to show an increase
>   in time spent on page by the user because the new content loads
>   automatically.

**How to Add Infinite Scroll in WordPress**

> First thing you need to do is install and activate the [Infinite Scroll plugin.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/)
>
> Upon activation, a new menu option will be added under your settings
>   tab called Infinite Scroll. On almost 90% of the blog sites, this
>   should work without changing a single setting. However, if you have a
>   relatively custom designed blog, then you will need to adjust the
>   “Selectors”. Go the plugin’s setting page and click on the selectors
>   tab.

[plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/)

[Documentation 1](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

[documentation 2](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/)